# How to get all the values of a table's column from a sqlQuery in Java?

Tags: java, sql, arrays

what I want is to get all the values that are into a column that i call in query from Java to SQL Server, I think it is like this:

```
public ArrayList createArray(ResultSet data){
    try {
        ArrayList arrayData = (ArrayList) data.getArray(1);//get all the data from the resultSet that's into the column 1
        return arrayData;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {/*Error message*/return null;}
}
```

But actually I don't know what does `getArray()` returns, and I don't find any information about it.
If someone can help, I'll be thankful.
Also if `getArray()` doesn't work like I think it does, could you please tell me how to do what I want?

Comment: is this your code? if it is your code how you do not know what getArray returns here?

Comment: can you post your code which is related how your retrieve data?

Comment: i only want the data from the fist column called in the query, so that's what it should return, but what i need is to know what does getArray do?, i mean i created the code, but just assuming that getArray returns all the data called from a column

Comment: the only point that I can tell you is you may have a array which you want to access its content by using getArray method. it is called getters

Comment: ok, is there any way to get all the rows data from a single column of a query and set them into a List or Array using jdbc?
    Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:
 [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`.
The post author will always be notified of your comment.
To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.
Learn more…

Comment: what you mean all rows from single column? do you mean a column?

Comment: can you post code or info about your project?

Comment: I don't post too much info because almost everytime my questions are unpriced, and then i can't ask anymore, can we contact through other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this :

```
List list = new ArrayList();
while (resultSetObject.next()) {
    list.add(resultSetObject.getString("columnName"));
}
```

You can convert it to String array if you want which I think is not necessary

```
String[] arrOfString = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard jdbc approach, which requires lots of boilerplate code and temporary variables, and the same thing with a more elegant add-on library, jdbi, which lets you use a much simpler fluent API:

jdbi approach:

```
public static List<String> jdbiEmployeeNameQuery(Handle h) {
    return h.createQuery("select name from employees order by id").map(StringMapper.FIRST).list();
}
```

jdbc approach:

```
public static List<String> jdbcEmployeeNameQuery(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException {
    try (Statement s = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select name from employees order by id")) {
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                names.add(rs.getString(1));
            }

            return names;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any similar in jdbc ?

Comment: Yes, straight JDBC just involves a ton of boilerplate code.

Comment: :s, can you give me an example?

Comment: there you go! Added to the answer.